# How to tell a rightCalloutAccessoryView has been touched for MapKit

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

I have a MKAnnotationView being allocated with a DetailDisclosure button being displayed on the right side of the annotation. How would I go about knowing when a user clicked on the annotation button? This is what my code looks like right now -

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
```

Is there a built in method to detect when a accessory view has been touched? I'm guessing it would be like the UITableView methods, but I can't find anything. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some object to be set as your map view's `delegate`, and implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol method `-mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method in your MKMapViewDelegate.

Comment: How would I fetch which indexPath has been clicked on? I tried the .tag but didn't work

Comment: What is indexPath when you're using MKMapAnnotations? You can get annotation object associated with annotation view through view's annotation property.

Comment: I have multiple annotations layed out on the map and I just want to make sure that once the user hits one of them, I have a way to tell which one was hit appropriately.

Comment: see my previous comment - you can get annotation object from annotation view - 2nd parameter of delegate method you must implement