# iPhone:Mapview move pin issue

Tags: iphone

I have Mapview and I successfully plot all pins on map and when I select a pin also add one button which is rightCalloutAccessoryView and when I click on button at that time I want to move all pins and selected pin display in center of mapview so please give me idea to develop this functionality..

Sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When the button is pushed, calculate the latitude/longitude range of all your pins, make an MKCoordinateRegion based on that, then use the MKMapView

```
- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated
```

To zoom to that region.

Comment: please give me any link or tutorial

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607431/how-to-tell-a-rightcalloutaccessoryview-has-been-touched-for-mapkit shows you how to intercept the tap on accessory view, then you get all annotation objects and make a region based on their coordinates.